# C++: saving derived class in shared_ptr of base class

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr

I want to have a class that has a shared pointer as member:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    shared_ptr<MyAbstractBaseClass> myPointer;
}
```

How can I make the pointer point to an instance of a derived class?

Comment: `myPointer.reset(new SomethingDerivedFromMyAbstractBaseClass());` would be one way. There are others. See the member links of [`std::shared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is about assigning a plain derived pointer, all you have to do is:

```
struct B { };
struct D : B { }; 

D *pd = new D; 
shared_ptr<B> sp(pd);
```

If the question is to convert a shared_ptr to a derived to shared_ptr to a base class, you can do this:

```
shared_ptr<D> spd = make_shared<D>(); 
shared_ptr<B> sp = static_pointer_cast<B>(spd);
```